# Вылетает ошибка java.util.zip.ZipException при сборке apk

Tags: java, android, gradle

Добрый день, StackOverflow.

При сборке apk столкнулся с такой проблемой:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils.class.

Все что нашел по этому вопросу перепробывал, но не помогает.

Вот мой build.gradle файл:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.0.0'



buildscript {


    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.carshering'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/pixplicity/maven" }
    maven { url 'https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}



android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.carshering"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 38
        versionName "1.15.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries false
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])



    compile ('org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2') { exclude module: 'commons-io' }
//  compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'{
//      exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
//  }


    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test:runner:0.5") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    compile ('com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:1.7.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
    }

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

//  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
//  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
//  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0.1'
    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0.1'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.2.1'
    compile 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.8.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.ryanharter.android.tooltips:library:0.0.3'
    compile 'org.json:json:20140107'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

За любую оказанную помощь, заранее, спасибо.

Comment: А зачем в зависимостях дважды `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'`?

Comment: @AlexChermenin, эх, спасибо. Пришел на проект, там были дупликаты в грэдле были и их удалил, но этот просто в упор не заметил.. Проблема решена

Comment: почитайте ещё https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration и перейдите с apt на annotationProcessor. со следующей версии Gradle Plugin apt не работает и не будет

Comment: @DeKaNszn, спасибо, сейчас почитаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была решена тем, что удалил лишнюю зависимость в gradle, которую не заметил. Спасибо @AlexChermenin, за быструю помощь..